# JLabel doesn't display anything in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I think and hope this is a minor issue.

I have a `JFrame` which gets displayed in a snake game. The text, e.g `"Game Over, your snake is crashed"` or something, will display in a `JLabel`.

The problem is my `JLabel` is always empty!

Here's the code:

```
package ch.gibb.snake1;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class endFrame extends JFrame {

        /**
         * Auto-generated VersionUID
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6535942219723507798L;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            displayFrame();
        }
        public static void displayFrame() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Over");
            JLabel info = new JLabel("My 127.0.0.1 is my castle", JLabel.CENTER);

            int height = 670;
            int width = 630;

            Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            int ex = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 4); // Center horizontally.
            int ey = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 4); // Center vertically.

            frame.setTitle("Game Over");
            frame.setBounds(ex, ey, width / 2, height / 2);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            info.setBounds(ex, ey, width/2, height/2);

            frame.add(info);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    frame.setTitle("Game Over");
    frame.setBounds(ex, ey, width / 2, height / 2);
    //frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //info.setBounds(ex, ey, width / 2, height / 2);
```

End result:

[image: End Game]

Comment: Ah ok cool. Ehm, i just replace the ex & ey by info with 0... It works also. What is better?

Comment: Definitely to use layouts is better than exact positioning.  That way the layout can figure where to put the components, based on their content and natural size.

Answer (score 0):

The `JLabel` doesnt display as you have set the X & Y co-ordinates to be outside of the `JFrames` dimensions here:

```
info.setBounds(ex, ey, width / 2, height / 2);
```

You need to set make this call on the `JFrame`.

```
frame.setBounds(ex, ey, width / 2, height / 2);
```

Also using a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) will remove the need to set bounds on child components themselves.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Just replace ex & ey with 0! :D